# two dimension set has been clear when clear the temp set

Tags: java, set

as this picture showed, it print out nothing..
trying to add new set element to set1, but once i clear the temp set2, it also clear set1. 
Is this because that when i add set2 to set1, it is just add the address of set2 to it instead of actual value?

```
   Set<Set<Integer>> set1 = new HashSet<>();
   Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>();
   set2.add(1);
   set2.add(1);
   set2.add(2);
   set1.add(set2);
   set2.clear();
   p.pp(set1);//print out 2-D set
   p.p(set2);//print out 1-D set
```

Comment: I don't see any print statement. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: what picture???

Comment: *Is this because that when i add set2 to set1, it is just add the address of set2 to it instead of actual value?* Pretty much. Also known as a reference.

Comment: It's because you made a change to an object (`set2`) that is inside a HashSet (`set1`), and that change affected it's `hashCode` and its `equals` method. The behaviour of `HashSet` is undefined if you do that - it likely cannot find your `set2` anymore because it is no longer in the right hash bucket.

Comment: Sorry, i cant add a picture now due to my low credit. The picture is same as the code attached

Comment: p.p is the method to print set and p.pp is for 2-d set. sorry for the unclear...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your comments. got it, i have to creat new set when i want to add another set to 2-D set, cant modify old one and use it again.